# Bounding cubes in higher dimensions

Tags: geometry

For any 2D shape, a perfect bounding square can be drawn around it such that each side of the square touches the shape. An intuitive (but not rigorous) proof can be found at 5:15 [here](https://youtu.be/aCj3qfQ68m0). Do all 3D shapes have bounding cubes? What about in higher dimensions?

Comment: What are your thoughts? Can you think of any relevant definitions?